# Getting user info through itsdangerous token

Tags: python, flask, token

I am currently learning Flask through Miguel Grinberg's book. If you are familiar you might know [Flasky](http://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/) (An application that Miguel use during the book)

I am currently in section 8, dealing with Password Reset, here the **original code** (you can also find it on the repo. it's tag 8g):

**models.py**

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ...
    def generate_reset_token(self, expiration=3600):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expiration)
        return s.dumps({'reset': self.id})

    def reset_password(self, token, new_password):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except:
            return False
        if data.get('reset') != self.id:
            return False
        self.password = new_password
        db.session.add(self)
        return True
```

**auth/views.py**

```
@auth.route('/reset/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def password_reset(token):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    form = PasswordResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
        if user.reset_password(token, form.password.data):
            flash('Your password has been updated.')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('auth/reset_password.html', form=form)
```

**auth/forms.py**

```
class PasswordResetForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 64),
                                             Email()])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', validators=[
        Required(), EqualTo('password2', message='Passwords must match')])
    password2 = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Reset Password')

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first() is None:
            raise ValidationError('Unknown email address.')
```

## My question:

I don't want to ask the user for their email again since they are changing the password through an email they have received. Is there a way to get the user or user's email from that token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so in case this could be useful for someone else. The user info is already in the token, in the {'reset': user_id}.

The problem is that token management logic is in User model. So having an email field in the form for later finding that user in the view does the trick in the current version

Since you get the token in this view we can move that logic to the view:

**auth/views.py**

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer

@auth.route('/reset/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password(token):
    s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        data = s.loads(token)
    except:
        raise ValidationError()
    user_id = data['reset']
    ....
```

And in User model, we  need to modify the reset_password() method:

**models.py**

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    ...

    def reset_password(self, new_password):
        self.password = new_password
        db.session.add(self)
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

For 1— On a security level, it can be nice advantage to your users to hide who has accounts with your site. for instance, lets say it was a Addicts Anonymous site, if I wanted to see if `alice@example.com` was a member, I could simply try a password reset to confirm she's a member.

Alternatively if you had a large collection of email addresses, you could use that password reset form to narrow down the list to active members for use in a more targeted social engineering attack, or at least narrow the list down if you're aiming to brute-force them.

Comment: Oh well, now that you mention it, it's true! I didn't thought about it

Comment: I have changed the whole question, do you have any clue how can do that?